# Draw figure using Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

everyone! 
can someone help me to draw this picture in Latex using Tikz !!
Thank you[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You question is a do-it-for-me question, where you ask the people on the site to do all of the work. That is not really the goal of the site. The goal is to ask a specific question about a problem that you encounter, such as "how do I draw an outline in a grid" or something similar. Importantly, such a question should show the code of what you already have done, so it is easy to add the necessary impovements. If you didn't try anything, then you should try first and then ask when you get stuck.

Answer (score 3):

This is to give you an idea how one may produce such things.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/dots/.style={code={
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dots/##1}}
 \tikzset{dots/.cd,#1} 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextx}{ifthenelse(\pv{xmin}+\pv{xstep}==int(\pv{xmin}+\pv{xstep}),
    int(\pv{xmin}+\pv{xstep}),\pv{xmin}+\pv{xstep}}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\nexty}{ifthenelse(\pv{ymin}+\pv{ystep}==int(\pv{ymin}+\pv{ystep}),
    int(\pv{ymin}+\pv{ystep}),\pv{ymin}+\pv{ystep}}
 \fill foreach \XX in {\pv{xmin},\nextx,...,\pv{xmax}}
  {foreach \YY in {\pv{ymin},\nexty,...,\pv{ymax}} 
  {(\XX,\YY) circle[radius=\pv{r}]}};
 }},
 dots/.cd,r/.initial=2pt,xmin/.initial=0,xmax/.initial=0,
 ymin/.initial=0,ymax/.initial=0,xstep/.initial=1,ystep/.initial=1,
 /tikz/pics/sil/.style={code={
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sil/##1}}
 \draw (45:\pv{r}) foreach \XX in {1,...,4} 
 {to[out=\XX*90-\pv{alpha},in=\XX*90+\pv{alpha},looseness=\pv{l}]
 (\XX*90+45:\pv{r})} --cycle;
 }},/tikz/sil/.cd,alpha/.initial=20,r/.initial=0.5,l/.initial=5,
 /tikz/pics/cir/.style={code={ 
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cir/##1}}
 \draw  circle[radius=\pv{R}];
 \foreach \XX in {1,...,8} 
 {\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (\XX*45:\pv{r});}}},
 /tikz/cir/.cd,R/.initial=1.6cm,r/.initial=1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
 \path pic{dots={ymin=0,ymax=7,xmin=0,xmax=6}}
  (5,1) pic{sil} (2,3) pic{sil} (1,6) pic{sil} (4,6) pic{sil};

 \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm,yshift=2cm,tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.7]
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=8,transform shape]
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
   \pic{dots={xmax=8,ymax=8}};
   \draw (4,4) pic{cir};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=8,transform shape]
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
   \pic{dots={xmax=8,ymax=7}};
   \draw (4,4) pic{cir};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=8,transform shape]
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
   \pic{dots={xmax=8,ymax=7,r=1.5pt}};
   \draw (4,4) pic{cir};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please use it as a start (and not as an anchor to make further requests).

Comment: Thank you very much!! it will help me a lot ... thank you again